# Several Threads listening on one UDP port?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp

I have a problem. I have a client program that listens on an UDP port for servers. These servers send packets (one each second) with their TCP port inside. These ports are how the servers are identified. When such a packet arrives for the first time, the server is stored in a centralized collection. If a server fails to send these packets for 5 seconds, this server is considered offline and being removed from the collection.

What I would like to do is to spawn a new thread for each server. This thread should only listen to one server. If a server times out, the thread removes the server from the collection and terminates itself.

I have implemented this with a *ThreadPool*, but it is not working at all.  What I figured out so far is, that probably due to the checks of the different threads if a packet is indeed the one it should listen to, the order of the incoming packets is completely messed up, resulting in chaotic removing and adding of servers to the collection.

Is there a possibility that more than one thread can listen to one single UDP port? How could I realize the desired behavior?

Thank you for your help!

*edit*

In the main Thread:

```
datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(udpPort);
datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

as well as in the new Thread.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 [java]     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:95)
 [java]     at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:376)
 [java]     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:231)
 [java]     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:284)
 [java]     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:256)
 [java]     at proxy.ServerHandler.<init>(ServerHandler.java:32)
 [java]     at proxy.DatagramSocketListener.run(DatagramSocketListener.java:59)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

*edit 2*

Thanks again! But now in the main thread:

```
datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
datagramSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(udpPort));
```

in the new thread:

```
datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
datagramSocket.connect(server.getAddress(), udpPort);
```

results in:

```
 [java] java.net.SocketException: already bound
 [java]     at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:360)
 [java]     at proxy.DatagramSocketListener.<init>(DatagramSocketListener.java:33)
 [java]     at proxy.ProxyCli.<init>(ProxyCli.java:74)
 [java]     at proxy.ProxyCli.main(ProxyCli.java:30)
```

but it is the first time I am initializing a DatagramSocket???

Answer (score -1):

Create a new socket on the same port in the new thread. You will have to set SO_REUSEADDR on all the sockets including the original one to make this possible. Then, connect the new socket to the desired target. Then that socket will only receive datagrams from that target.

Comment: Thank you, but I always get a java.net.BindException: Address already in use. I am using datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true) on both Sockets.

Comment: You need to call that before you bind.

Comment: Thanks, but there's another problem.

Comment: Ahhh, I should have initialized it with NULL! Thank you again, it's working now! :-)